# Getting error: unknown flag: --tcp while creating service in KUbernetes

Tags: kubernetes

when I give this command :

```
kubectl create service NodePort nginx --tcp = 80:80
```

I get the below error,

```
error: unknown flag: --tcp
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Hi, did you try running `kubectl create service --help`?

Comment: yes, did not help

Comment: It should have told you what the correct commandline parameters are - I take it that there is no `--tcp` parameter. Are you following a tutorial or similar?

Comment: It seems that you should be using `--tcp=80:80` (no spaces). Here's the manual: https://www.mankier.com/1/kubectl-create-service-nodeport. Also,I don't know if the command is case sensitive, but the example shows `nodeport`, not `NodePort`.

Comment: It seems that the commands are case-sensitive. It is working after changing it to nodeport.  Thanks